# How can I convert JSON to an object?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I'm very new to C# and playing around with Visual Studio and Xamarin.
I have a web service where I get a JSON result from looking like this:

```
{"Vorname": "MYNAME", "AusweisNr": "894", "MitgliedsNr": "33203", "returnstr": "None", "returncode": "0"}
```

What I'm trying to do is to use the data I get to fill some text fields with, but I don't understand how to get it converted. I've already played around a bit with `JsonConvert` but couldn't get it working.

Comment: What do you want to convert it to?

Comment: Please don't use hashtags in your question title.

Comment: Hey @Phillip.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Read here about writing a good SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This does not answer the question but when i started app development in xamarin this article was a good start: http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/

Answer (score 4):

Create a class with those properties:

```
public class SomeMeaningfulName
{
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string AusweisNr { get; set; }
    public string MitgliedsNr { get; set; }
    public string returnstr { get; set; }
    public string returncode { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize the string into that class:

```
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeMeaningfulName>(yourJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string AusweisNr { get; set; }
    public string MitgliedsNr { get; set; }
    public string returnstr { get; set; }
    public string returncode { get; set; }
}
```

And to deserialize it:

```
string json = "{'Vorname': 'MYNAME', 'AusweisNr': '894', 'MitgliedsNr': '33203', 'returnstr': 'None', 'returncode': '0'}"
Person person = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person>(json);
```

In this case I use JavascriptSerializer because it very simple to use but you can also use JSONConverter if you realy need it

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert using JsonConvert, you need to have a class with fields that share the names of your JSON object and they all need to be public. Try this

```
class MyJsonObject
{
    public string Vorname;
    public int AusweisNr;
    public int MitgliedsNr;
    public string returnstr;
    public int returncode;
}
```

If you want, you could also make it a public property rather than a variable. To convert, you need to do something like this.

```
MyJsonObject obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJsonObject>(jsonData);
```

Where `jsonData` is a string containing your JSON code. You can then copy all the data to a text field.

Answer (score 0):

Get your JSON string and set in this  [WebSite](http://json2csharp.com/), this website will create a class object for you, take this object and put in your project.
example:

```
public class RootObject // object name
{
    //atributtes names
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string AusweisNr { get; set; }
    public string MitgliedsNr { get; set; }
    public string returnstr { get; set; }
    public string returncode { get; set; }
}
```

So you will dowloand this JSON and put in a String var
example:

```
var Apiurl = "http://youAPI.com/something/something/";
var JSONString= new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(Apiurl);//this will download all text what the Apiurl return
```

After that, you will put convert/Deserialize your JsonString in a object.

```
RootObject objectJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSONString);
```

whats happen in this last code?

```
yourJsonObject nameForThisObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourObjectJsonClass>(yourJsonString);
```

note: your ObjectJsonClass(my RootObject) must have the sames Json's attributes.